# What is the PF field in k9s?

Tags: kubernetes

In `k9s` (kubernetes management tool) what is the PF column (for pods)? What does the Ⓕ value mean?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "PF" field refers to port forwarding.

You may setup port forwarding, ("shift-f" in pod view). This indicator probably means you have setup some port forwarding -- in my case, it prints some weird character.

Although to be honest ... I only figured it out, searching their git repository history .... Introduced here: https://github.com/derailed/k9s/commit/f1111174aa8df815e25b0a029ba1465d3a855b49#diff-5b19eaab395254884c7dff045b0e50a599c29794e80a81fe42c9667450b6e9d4

Comment: Aha, so it wasn’t related to [Priority and Fairness](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/flow-control/); it is supposed to confirm my instrumentation rather than to indicate some misbehaviour of the workload that I was already probing. Good idea searching the git log (in hindsight perhaps I ought to have queried the source for that character).